# Do not save data from "combobox", only the last element from "checkedlistbox" is added

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm trying to drag information from one table to create a category in a dropdown list. Next, I want to read the selected items into the "checkedlistbox" and save them in a table. Unfortunately, in the first case, I can display the category in the drop-down list, but then they are not transferred to the database. When trying to save elements with "checkedlistbox", only one is saved, I think that maybe need to use an array and not a string.

This is where I fill in the "combobox":

```
        private void getCategory()
        {
            conn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            NpgsqlDataAdapter adap = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM workers", conn);
            adap.Fill(dt);
            cmbCoash.DataSource = dt;
            cmbCoash.DisplayMember = "name";
            cmbCoash.ValueMember = "name";
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Adding to the table:

```
                string Name = txtName.Text;
                string Type = txtType.Text;
                string Coash = cmbCoash.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string Days = "";

                  //checkedlistbox
                  foreach (object itemChecked in chDay.CheckedItems)
                  {
                      Days = itemChecked.ToString();
                  }

                var count = chDay.CheckedItems.Count;

                conn.Open();
                string query = $"INSERT INTO public.groupfit (name,type,trainingdays,сoach,total) VALUES('{Name}','{Type}','{Days}','{Coash}','{count}')";

                NpgsqlCommand nCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);
                nCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("Done.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                conn.Close();
                Select();
                cleaning();
```

[image: This is what the added entry looks like]
Do you really need to read "checkedlistbox" into an array for future storage?

Comment: You are looping and only setting the last element in the loop: Days = itemChecked.ToString();`  It's not clear what type `trainingdays` is in your table. Do use parameters to avoid sql injection.

Comment: getCategory() is used to fill in the "сoach" field, the type of this field in the database is "character varying".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean Days to be a comma delimited string.

If that is the case, replace this

```
foreach (object itemChecked in chDay.CheckedItems)
{
   Days = itemChecked.ToString();
}
```

with this

```
Days = string.Join(",", chDay.CheckedItems.Cast<object>().Select( x => x.ToString()) );
```

Comment: Doesn't skip "Select".

Comment: Try it with `Cast<object>()` (as edited)

Comment: Everything works, thank you for teaching me how to solve such problems. I am very grateful to you, may you always be happy.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the second problem that I described yesterday.

```
        private void getCategory()
    {
        string selectQuerry = "SELECT * FROM workers";
        NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(selectQuerry, conn);
        NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        cmbCoash.DataSource = table;
        cmbCoash.ValueMember = "name";
    }
```

And then this is how I get the variable to record it in the database:

```
string Coash = cmbCoash.Text;
```